# Can we push data to Kafka from Ansible without installing any extra python module on Ansible controller host (possibly Ansible Tower)?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, stream, ansible, producer

I need to push Ansible playbook logs to a Kafka topic using Ansible only. 
There are few limitations like:

1. We can not install any extra utility on the Ansible controller machine (Ansible tower).
2. We can not install any extra python module as well.

I have seen that there are ways like java, python etc but I could not find anything like that. 
As of now possible work arounds are:

1. Installing Kafka in Ansible controller machine.
2. Developing a custom module that will require Kafka python module to be installed on the controller machine again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, I think you could install kafka in the controller machine (or copy the folder, not needed to add it to the cluster) and use bin/kafka-console-producer.sh to push messages to kafka (piping the logs to it, for instance).

Comment: Thanks for the response Mise, Actually we are using Ansible tower as a controller. There we can not install any other utility because of organisaton policies.